# R and Julia Kernels not available in Jupyter notebook

Tags: r, ipython, julia, anaconda, jupyter

I recently installed the Anaconda3 distribution and I want to have the R and Julia Kernels available besides Python. I use windows 10.

To install IJulia I installed the Julia language and follewed the steps indicated in the [IJulia page](https://github.com/JuliaLang/IJulia.jl); everything went fine.

To install the R kernel I used the command `conda install -c r r-essentials` in the anaconda command prompt, again, no problems. I also installed R.

When I launch the notebook **the only available kernel is Python**, the R and Julia kernels doesn't appear in the list, I have no clue why this since I got no errors in the installation of IJulia and IRKernel. Anyone could help?

Comment: try rebuilding IJulia by `Pkg.build("IJulia")`.

Comment: your IRKernel [kernel specs](http://jupyter-client.readthedocs.org/en/latest/kernels.html#kernel-specs) should in this path `%PROGRAMDATA%\jupyter\kernels`.

Comment: What happens if you do: `using IJulia; notebook()` from Julia REPL?

Comment: upgrade your `ipython-notebook / jupyter` to 4.0 if you haven't done that yet, and re install `IJulia`

Comment: Reinstalling the Anaconda distribution worked, now i can use the R and Julia notebooks.

Answer (score 15):

### After a fresh installation of Anaconda Distribution (either 2 or 3), following steps should be performed to achieve the desired kernels (R & Julia) on your notebook.

**To install R on Anaconda(2/3) Jupyter Notebook :**

1. Open '**Anaconda Command Prompt**' & execute `conda update notebook` to update your Jupyter notebook to the most recent version.
2. Then install **IRkernel** by `conda install -c r notebook r-irkernel`
3. Now you may open **R** in your command prompt by running `R.exe`
4. Install all necessary **R** packages using the following lines in the **R** console by executing :

   `install.packages(c('repr', 'IRdisplay', 'evaluate', 'crayon', 'pbdZMQ', 
   'devtools', 'uuid', 'digest'))`

   `devtools::install_github('IRkernel/IRkernel')`
5. Finally, make the **R kernel** available to your Jupyter Notebook by executing:

   **Install only for the current user** ➡ `IRkernel::installspec()`

   **For System-wide installation(all Users)** ➡ `IRkernel::installspec(user = FALSE)`

**To install Julia on Anaconda(2/3) Jupyter Notebook :**

1. First, [download](http://julialang.org/downloads/) **Julia** *version 0.4 or later* and run the installer. Then run the Julia application (double-click on it); the **Julia Console** with a **julia>** prompt will appear.
2. Now, for the most important step, open '**Anaconda Command Prompt**' & execute `where jupyter` to see the actual path of your Jupyter Notebook. The output will be something like `"C:\Users\JohnDoe\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\bin\jupyter.exe"`
3. Copy the above location and go to your **Julia console**. Now, execute the following respectively:
   `ENV["JUPYTER"]="C:\\Users\\JohnDoe\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3\\bin\\jupyter.exe"`

   `Pkg.add("IJulia")`

   `Pkg.build("IJulia")` (*Optional, execute if further error occurs again.*)

   ⬆ *Notice that the backslashes have to be doubled when you type them as a Julia string. I've just assumed that the path is your Anaconda path with \bin\jupyter appended, but replace that with whatever `where jupyter` tells you.*
4. After few minutes, in **Julia console** execute:

   `using IJulia`
   `notebook()`

Now, you can program **Julia** in your **Anaconda Jupyter Notebook**.

Comment: `ENV["JUPYTER"]="C:\\Users\\JohnDoe\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3\\bin\\jupyter.exe"` was what I was missing. Note that for Anaconder 4, this is located under Scripts\jupyter.exe

Comment: I get this error: Error executing Jupyter command 'kernelspec': [Errno 'jupyter-kernelspec' not found] 2
│ [InstallKernelSpec] Removing existing kernelspec in C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\julia-1.0
│ [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\myuser\\AppData\\Roaming\\jupyter\\kernels\\julia-1.0\\logo-32x32.png'

Comment: Using `Pkg.build("IJulia")` was key for me.

Answer (score 1):

Excellent, it worked.
However, it is important to import the package first before adding it.

```
import Pkg; Pkg.add("IJulia")
```

Comment: This worked for me too! Thank you. https://github.com/JuliaLang/IJulia.jl/issues/968#issuecomment-739800974